# Normalize API data for use in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have the following data coming from an API:

```
const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'myboard',
  columns: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'col1',
      cards: [
        { id: 1, name: 'card1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'card2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'col2',
      cards: [
        { id: 3, name: 'card3' },
        { id: 4, name: 'card4' }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there are essentially 3 nested levels. The top level contains an `id`, `name` and a list of `columns`. Each `column` contains an `id`, `name` and a list of `cards`. Each `card` has an `id` and `name`.

I wish to normalize the data for use in Redux as presented [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape#designing-a-normalized-state). I am using [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to do this as follows:

```
const card = new schema.Entity('cards');
const column = new schema.Entity('columns', {
  cards: [card]
});
const board = new schema.Entity('boards', {
  columns: [column]
});

normalize(data, board)
```

This results in the following:

```
{
  "entities": {
    "cards": {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "card1"
      },
      "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "card2"
      },
      "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "card3"
      },
      "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "card4"
      }
    },
    "columns": {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "col1",
        "cards": [1, 2]
      },
      "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "col2",
        "cards": [3, 4]
      }
    },
    "boards": {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "myboard",
        "columns": [1, 2]
      }
    }
  },
  "result": 1
}
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to have each section (ie: `cards`, `columns`, `boards`) split into two sections, namely `byId` and `allIds` as per the Redux article referenced above.

Essentially this is to make ordering, sorting etc easier in a React application. Im using the latest version of normalizr (3.2.4).

Comment: The [next page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/updating-normalized-data) of the docs goes into that.  Essentially,  you will need to manage them yourself.

Comment: The next page details how to go about updating the store which is already in the right format. That all makes sense. However I am still unsure how to create the initial normalized structure in the first place. The initial data is coming from an API as per the example in my post, I then need to normalize it and include `byId` and `allIds` for each section. That's the part that im unsure about.

Comment: If I have time tomorrow, I'll do up an example as an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a CodeSandbox with an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3n5oqx3mx?expanddevtools=1&module=%2Freducers.js) of how you can set up the reducers to handle the normalized state.

Essentially, you will end up with something like this for each of your entities:

```
// lambda or function - whatever your preference is
const cardsById = (state = {}, action) => {
  // if, case, handler function - whatever your preference is
  if (action.type === 'ADD_DATA') { // or whatever your initial data load type is
    return { ...state, ...action.payload.cards }
  }
  return state
}

const allCards = (state = [], action) => {
  if (action.type === 'ADD_DATA') { // or whatever your initial data load type is
    return [...state, ...Object.keys(action.payload.cards)]
  }
  return state
}

const cards = combineReducers({
  byId: cardsById,
  allIds: allCards
})
```

and then combine all of those together:

```
export default combineReducers({
  cards,
  columns,
  boards
})
```

The action creators for this are as follows:

```
const addData = ({ entities }) => ({
  type: 'ADD_DATA',
  payload: entities // note the rename - this is not required, just my preference
})

// I used a thunk, but theory is the the same for your async middleware of choice
export const getData = () => dispatch => dispatch(addData(normalize(data, board)))
```

Hope this helps.  Remember that you will need to maintain both the `byId` and `allIds` for each entity as entities are added or removed.

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for example, too. But how to implement crosstabless in redux store? Say, if i have cards and card_members tables, how to implement relations between them? Because Normalizing State Shape redux docs says that Each type of data gets its own "table" in the state.